# Exception while creating new spring boot project in STS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have downloaded STS 3.9.0 and Java 8 is installed on my machine.When I open STS and try to create new "spring starter project I get following error".

[image: http://start.spring.io]

after researching I found that we can resolve this by changing url to "https://start.spring.io" this,but after doing that I get following error.

[image: https://start.spring.io]

Comment: I would recommend to download latest STS(4.4) and try, working fine with latest version.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation but I getting same error with STS(4.4) also.

Comment: First of all, changing to https is correct. The resulting exception is probably caused by the JDK not able to validate the certificate (or something like that) and that is something that you can solve in your JDK. There are a bunch of questions around this on SO, so I would recommend to search on SO for this `SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to request` message.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like connection or proxy issue.
Please check your connection or firewall settings which is used by STS.

And as a second option, you can use https://start.spring.io/ for generating project and can import in your IDE.

Comment: it seems problem with that only but I am unable figure out the solution.I have tried changing proxy setting to manual also.but still it is not working. Also want to mention that I am able access "https://start.spring.io" from my chrome broswer with same proxy setting.

Comment: Latest version for Eclipse STS is **spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.2.RELEASE** now. Try to use the updated version of Eclipse STS from [https://spring.io/tools]